# Wix and FinalBuilder - InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, wix, finalbuilder

While running a build in FinalBuilder, when it gets up to the Wix installer project and runs the linker `light.exe`, I get the following error 
`InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`
Does anyone know what could cause this?

This error is normally caused by adding or removing items from a collection while looping through it, but as far as I can tell my code isn't doing that, and it builds in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide some code here if you want a concrete answer, but from what I see you're having a loop over a collection and in that loop you modify this collection (remove, add items, etc.). You can't do that inside this loop using enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause is, but the FinalBuilder build runs successfully on the build server, just not on my machine.